# Historical report data

Tags: waze

Is there a way to access/request historical, user-reported event data? As a curiosity project, I'd like to analyze this to try and identify hot spots for accidents/traffic/police/etc.

There's definitely some great insights to be found in this data, I'd appreciate your help in getting there!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Waze partners can easily store data they get from Waze and use it for analysis. But  Waze does not share any historical data with partners. 

If you want, you can store the incident feeds in your own data storage everytime you accept a feed from Waze API

Comment: I see. What's the best way to set up such a feed for reported events in a specific geographical area?